# Guardar filas seleccionadas mediante checkbox dinamicos en tabla dinámica

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net, checkbox, aspx

¿Cómo hago para guardar(actualizar registro) en mi BD las filas seleccionadas por un `checkbox` y a la misma vez ese `checkbox` debe de cambiar a `true` (`checked`) o `false`?

Esto sería mi formulario `Default.aspx`:

```html
<div class="box" >
  <div class="box-header">
     <div class="box-tools">
        <div>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtId" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </div>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body table-responsive no-padding">                            
      <asp:Literal ID="Tabla1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
  </div>
   <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button"/>
</div>
```

Codebehind: `Default.aspx.cs`

```cs
protected void cargatablaProfesional(string RED, string MRED, string EESS)
{
    string varSql = "SELECT [id],[dni],[cod_eess],[actguardia] 
FROM[BDPROGRAMACION].[dbo].[AsignacionGuardias] WHERE cod_eess like '%" + 
EESS + "%'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(varSql, con);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

    adapter.SelectCommand = cmd;
    DataSet objdataset = new DataSet();
    adapter.Fill(objdataset);

    DataTable dtDato = objdataset.Tables[0];


    dibujatabla(dtDato);
}

public void dibujatabla(DataTable dtDato)
{
    string html = "";

    int cont = 0;
    //string chkd="";

    if (dtDato.Rows.Count > 0)
    {

        html = "<table class='table table-condensed' style='text-align: right; font-size: 12px; background-color: #fff;'>";
        html += "<tr>";
        html += "<th class='' hidden>id</th>";
        html += "<th class=''>DNI</th>";
        html += "<th class=''>cod_eess</th>";
        html += "<th class=''>checkbox</th>";
        html += "</tr>";

        foreach (DataRow dbRow in dtDato.Rows)
        {

                cont++;


            html += "<tr>";
            html += "<td class='' style='text-align: left;' hidden>" + dbRow["id"].ToString() + "</td>";
            html += "<td class='' style='text-align: left;'>" + dbRow["dni"].ToString() + "</td>";
            html += "<td class='' style='text-align: left;'>" + dbRow["cod_eess"].ToString() + "</td>";
            html += "<td class='' style='text-align: left;'><input type='checkbox' id='" + cont + "'></td>";


            html += "</tr>";

        }
        html += "</table>";
    }
    else
    {
        html += "<table>";
        html += "<tr><td class='FieldCaption' colspan=3>Sin registros encontrados</td></tr>";
        html += "</table>";
    }


    Tabla1.Text = html;
}
```

Como pueden ver, mi tabla primero lo dibujo y luego lo mando mediante un literal mediante un `<asp:literal>`

¿Cómo hago para poder enviar mediante un botón las filas seleccionadas mediante `checkbox` y a la vez actualizar el campo de la tabla "`[actguardia]`" mediante `true` o `false`

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}
```

Comment: no recomiendo la forma en que generas la tabla en asp.net, usa el GridView y asigna el DataSource con el datatable para que genere las rows, si te interesa este camino te respondo explicando como usar el checkbox dentro de una columna del GridView. Pero no generes la tabla de esa forma es incorrecto en asp.net

Comment: por favor Leandro, necesito conocer mas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para definir una tabla con `checkbox` en su columna usa el control `GridView` al cual le asignaras de datasource el `datatable`

Puedes definir todo de forma visual arrastando controles a las columna template del grid

[Agregar una columna GridView de casillas de verificación (C#)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/enhancing-the-gridview/adding-a-gridview-column-of-checkboxes-cs)

O puedes definir el html del grid, algo como ser:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" DataKeyNames="id">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="dni" HeaderText="DNI" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="cod_eess" HeaderText="cod_eess" />
        <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="chkRow" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

entonces para asignar los datos usarias

```
protected void cargatablaProfesional(string RED, string MRED, string EESS)
{
    string varSql = "SELECT [id],[dni],[cod_eess],[actguardia] 
                        FROM[BDPROGRAMACION].[dbo].[AsignacionGuardias] WHERE cod_eess like '%' + @EESS +'%'";

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(varSql, con);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EESS", EESS);
    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    adapter.Fill(dt);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.Databind();
}
```

para recuperar en el boton la seleccion iteras las rows tomando la seleccion

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {
                string id = GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value;
                //aqui codigo
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Es importante conocer como trabajar con este control

[GridView with CheckBox: Get Selected Rows in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/GridView-with-CheckBox-Get-Selected-Rows-in-ASPNet.aspx)

y usar el `DataKeyNames` y `DataKeys` para obtener el id oculto que reprsenta a la entidad de la row selecionada

[DataKeyNames in GridView example in ASP.Net](https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/DataKeyNames-in-GridView-example-in-ASPNet.aspx)

Nota: usa siempre parametros en el SELECT

Answer (score 2):

utilicé tu código de la siguiente manera

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView1.Rows)
    {
        if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            CheckBox chkRow = (row.FindControl("chkRow") as CheckBox);
            int id = Convert.ToInt32(GridView1.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
            if (chkRow.Checked)
            {                    
                updaterow(id, "true");
            }
            else
            {
               updaterow(id, "false");
            }
        }
    }
}

private  void updaterow(int rollno, String markstatus)
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_actualizaAsignacion", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int);
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@actguardia", SqlDbType.Bit);
    //asignamos los valores
    cmd.Parameters["@id"].Value = rollno;
    cmd.Parameters["@actguardia"].Value = markstatus;
    con.Open();
    //ejecutamos la instruccion con ExcecuteNonQuerry indicando que no retorna registros.
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    //Label1.Text = "Usuario ingresado...";
    //cerramos conexion
    con.Close();

}
```

Procedimiento almacenado

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sp_actualizaAsignacion]
@actguardia nvarchar(255),
@id int

as 

UPDATE BDPROGRAMACION.dbo.AsignacionGuardias
set actguardia=@actguardia
where id=@id
```

Logré actualizar el campo [actguardia] de mi tabla.

Comment: gracias Leandro!